# Add xmlns attribute to root element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have C# Program to Generate RDL File For whitch Show report in Reporting services.
I use Linq to Xml to generate Xml.

When I try to add **xmlns** XAttribute to Report Element, I encounter several problems.

I test following methods:

**first:**

```
        XDocument d = new XDocument(
           new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
           new XElement("Report",
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "cl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition"),
               new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"),
                   new XElement("DataSources", ""),
                   new XElement("DataSets", ""),
                   new XElement("ReportSections",
```

this is a part of my code witch show how generate xml:

**second:**

```
XNamespace reportDef = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition";
        XDocument d = new XDocument(
           new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
           new XElement(reportDef + "Report",
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "cl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition"),
                   new XElement("DataSources", ""),
                   new XElement("DataSets", ""),
                   new XElement("ReportSections",...
```

The first method returns an Error and second method adds attribute **xmlns** to all child node.

I want this format:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add you child nodes using the `XNamespace` as described in [How to: Create a Document with Namespaces (C#) (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx)

```
XNamespace reportDef = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition";
XElement root = new XElement(reportDef + "Report",
    new XElement(reportDef + "Child", "child content"));
```

This should give you the desired result.

You can also add a default namespace by adding an `xmlns` attribute

```
XElement xe = new XElement(reportDef + "Report",
    new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"),
    new XElement(reportDef + "Child", "child content"));
```

Comment: I use this solution but Unfortunately as before this attribute add to all child nodes.

Comment: Seems odd since I can't reproduce this. Try adding the default namespace attribute as in my second example. Maybe update your question and show more of your actual code.

Comment: If you have any example like this please send it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from @Filburt's answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874422/how-to-set-the-default-xml-namespace-for-an-xdocument) post, that xmlns attribute is a special attribute. It can only be accessed through XNamespace class.

Below I will give you an example on how to create namespaces. You should look at [How to: Create a Document with Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) for more information. The reason your code is adding **xmlns** tags to all the children is because you are not creating all child nodes in the same namespace.

1. To put elements in the default namespace, create a `XNamespace` (see ns1 below) and prepend the value to the element name. Ex: `new XElement(ns1 + "Report");` This creates an element `<Report>` in the ns1 namespace and doesn't have a prefix.
2. To add additional namespaces, add an attribute with the namespace and prefix. For example, `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns2", ns2)` adds a namespace to the `<Report>` element with the `ns2` prefix. After this, each time you create an element (`new XElement(ns2+"DataSources")`) with the ns2 namespace, the prefix will be used. The prefix can be used in all the descendants below the element with the prefix declaration. This is where you made a mistake.

   ```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
       xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
       xws.Indent = true;

       using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
       {   
           XNamespace ns1 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition";
           XNamespace ns2 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";
           XNamespace ns3 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition";
           XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
           XElement reportElement = new XElement(ns1 + "Report",
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns2", ns2),
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns3", ns3));
           doc.Add(reportElement);

           reportElement.Add(new XElement(ns2+"DataSources"));
           reportElement.Add(new XElement(ns3+"DataSets"));
           reportElement.Add(new XElement(ns1+"ReportSections"));

           doc.WriteTo(xw);
       }

       System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());
   ```

Comment: Yes all child node create same way. I edit first and second sample Code. please check it. thanks

Comment: @AmirReza I've added an example and noted your mistake. Basically, you needed to put `new XElement(reportDef+"DataSources", "")` instead of `new XElement("DataSources", "")`. The namespace was missing in the children so they'd end up in the empty namespace.