# How to specify an xmlns for XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, linq-to-xml

I tried:

```
textBox1.Text = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root1", new XAttribute( "xmlns", @"http://example.com"), new XElement("a", "b"))
).ToString();
```

But I get:

```
The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://example.com' within the same start element tag.
```

I also tried substituting (according to an answer I found) :

```
XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns,...
```

But got an error as well.

**Note**: I'm not trying to have more than one xmlns in the document.

Comment: Maybe this work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2874572/1373170

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way the `XDocument` API works with namespace-scoped names is as `XName` instances. These are fairly easy to work with, as long as you accept that an XML name isn't just a string, but a scoped identifier. Here's how I do it:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://example.com");
var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
var root = new XElement(ns + "root1", new XElement(ns + "a", "b"));
doc.Add(root);
```

Result:

```
<root1 xmlns="http://example.com">
    <a>b</a>
</root1>
```

Note the `+` operator is overloaded to accept an `XNamespace` and a `String` to result in and `XName` instance.

Comment: Thanks. It seems strange that there won't be a _simple_ way to add a namespace only once.

Comment: Well, I think this is fairly simple, and it really drives home that what you are doing is creating namespaced names, not just strings. If you want less code for namespaces, the `System.Xml.XmlDocument` class uses a Namespace manager to keep track of the root namespace, and you can pretend like it doesn't exist once you get it setup right.

Comment: See my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841517/how-can-i-add-innerxml-without-it-being-modified-in-any-way - I'm trying `XmlDocument` as well and it's not helping.

Comment: For me this does not add the xmlns to my root1 equivalent but instead to every single descendant - is there a way to add it just as xmlns instead?

Comment: @Sam - If all the child elements have the same namespace, then when you convert the XML document to a string, the output mechanism can optionally elide the namespace declaration on child elements. So, if you're seeing `xmlns` on the child elements, check how you're outputting it. Additionally, the presence of the namespace attribute on elements should not affect the actual meaning of the XML document.

Comment: Yup, after some fiddling around I managed to add the Namespace in a way which made the output mechanism work like I wanted it to.