# How can I add InnerXml without it being modified in any way?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to find a *simple* way to add XML to XML-with-xmlns without getting the `xmlns=""` nor having to specify the `xmlns` every time.

I tried both `XDocument` and `XmlDocument` but couldn’t find a simple way. The closest I got was doing this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode docNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xml.AppendChild(docNode);
XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("root", @"http://example.com");
xml.AppendChild(root);

root.InnerXml = "<a>b</a>";
```

But what I get is this:

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
  <a xmlns="">b</a>
</root>
```

So: Is there a way to set the `InnerXml` without it being modified?

Comment: the xmlns="" is because you're adding elements from a different namespace. Add them to the parent element's namespace and you shouldn't see the xmlns="" part

Comment: As I wrote - I'm trying _not_ to have to specify the namespace in every node.

Comment: just take if from the parent, no need to hard-code it

Comment: xml elements' identity includes both their name and namespace. what you're seeing is XmlDocument attempting to preserve the identity you pass along, it's not making things up

Comment: Thanks for your input. But the question is clear so I won't argue about it.

Comment: The question is clear but it's also clear you're a bit fuzzy on the cause of that xmlns="" (:

Comment: I think you question is unclear.  from the accepted answer it seems you want to not to have to specify the namespace in the **code** but have the xml that is generated to be in the same namespace as the root element.  This is not clear (at least to me) from your question or comments.  It seems like you wanted the generated xml not to contain the additional namespace elements

Comment: @SamHolder Thanks for clarifying that. (I'm _not_ being sarcastic.)

Comment: @ispiro np. glad you got your problem sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `a` `XmlElement` the same way you create the `root` element, and specify the `InnerText` of that element.

Option 1:

```
string ns = @"http://example.com";

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode docNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xml.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("root", ns);
xml.AppendChild(root);

XmlElement a = xml.CreateElement("a", ns);
a.InnerText = "b";
root.AppendChild(a);
```

Option 2:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlNode docNode = xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
xml.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlElement root = xml.CreateElement("root");
xml.AppendChild(root);
root.SetAttribute("xmlns", @"http://example.com");

XmlElement a = xml.CreateElement("a");
a.InnerText = "b";
root.AppendChild(a);
```

Resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
    <a>b</a>
</root>
```

If you use `root.InnerXml = "<a>b</a>";` instead of creating the `XmlElement` from the `XmlDocument` the resulting XML is:

Option 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
    <a xmlns="">b</a>
</root>
```

Option 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
    <a xmlns="http://example.com">b</a>
</root>
```

Comment: As I wrote - I'm trying _not_ to have to specify the namespace in every node.

Comment: @ispiro it won't add the namespace to every node, but in order to avoid having multiple `xmlns` attributes you will need to specify when you create them that they are in the same namespace.  I know it is rather annoying to have to specify the namespace over and over again for every `XmlElement` that you create, but to get XML you desire that's what you'll need to do.

Comment: and I think what has been suggested is a solution to that.  the namespace will only be at the root node if you do this.  The reason its displayed as `xmlns=""` in the child node is because its in a *different namespace to the parent*

Comment: @SamHolder & JG in SD - I understand that. But as I wrote - I'm trying **not** to have to specify the namespace in every node. Look at your code. It **does**!

Comment: Thank you very much for your perseverance. Your solution works perfectly (even with `root.InnerXml = "<a>b</a>";`).

Comment: @ispiro it worked w/ `root.InnerXml = "<a>b</a>";`?  I tried that and what I had the resulting XML wasn't what you were looking for.  What was your code?

Comment: @JGinSD The only change I made to my original code (in the question) was to add `root.SetAttribute("xmlns", @"http://example.com");` after appending the root.

Comment: @JGinSD he wasn't bothered about the resulting xml, it was the code he didn't want to specify the namespace in I believe

Comment: @SamHolder Yes. He understood that. He's referring to the result in Option 2 which has an extra namespace.

Comment: @ispiro Exactly, just trying to make sure the code and the resulting XML are what you want.