# Specifiying a default namespace for XDocument gives empty value

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

When I try to parse XDocument from text, I can get the default namespace like this:

```
var xmlDocument1 = XDocument.Parse("<root xmlns='http://somenamespace'></root>");
var xmlNamespace1 = xmlDocument1.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName; // somenamespace
```

However, if I try to create XDocument manually, I'm getting an empty value:

```
var xmlRoot2 = new XElement(XName.Get("root", "http://somenamespace"));
var xmlDocument2 = new XDocument(xmlRoot2);
var xmlNamespace2 = xmlDocument2.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName; // is empty
```

I expect xmlNamespace2 to be "http://somenamespace". Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** The answer in suggested duplicate doesn't solve my problem, even if I use the function suggested here:
[How to set the default XML namespace for an XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874422/how-to-set-the-default-xml-namespace-for-an-xdocument)
I will still get the empty namespace. Here is the solution from the linked question:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlRoot = new XElement(XName.Get("root"));
        var xmlDocument = new XDocument(xmlRoot);
        SetDefaultXmlNamespace(xmlRoot, "http://somenamespace");
        var xmlNamespace = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName; // is empty
    }

    public static void SetDefaultXmlNamespace(XElement xelem, XNamespace xmlns)
    {
        if (xelem.Name.NamespaceName == string.Empty)
            xelem.Name = xmlns + xelem.Name.LocalName;
        foreach (var e in xelem.Elements())
            SetDefaultXmlNamespace(e, xmlns);
    }
}
```

The default namespace is still empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default XML namespace for an XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874422/how-to-set-the-default-xml-namespace-for-an-xdocument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand why I don't get the default namespace. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When creating XML trees using C#, even if an XML tree would be
>   serialized with a default namespace, if the namespace is not persisted
>   in the XML tree as an attribute, this method will not report the
>   namespace as the default namespace.

So I probably need to set the xmlns attribute explicitly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlRoot = new XElement(XName.Get("root", "http://somenamespace"));
        xmlRoot.SetAttributeValue("xmlns", "http://somenamespace");
        var xmlDocument = new XDocument(xmlRoot);
        var xmlNamespace = xmlDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting the correct namespace name.

Comment: Yes, this is about the easiest way. I was looking for something cleverer but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, tricky because even as the string representation looks OK it still doesn't work.

For education, add this:

```
var xml3 = xmlDocument2.ToString();
var xmlDocument3 = XDocument.Parse(xml3);            
var xmlNamespace3 = xmlDocument3.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;
```

So only after you Parse the xml text again it is what you would expect.

The probably shortest way to do this:

```
var xmlRoot2 = new XElement(XName.Get("root", "http://somenamespace"), 
       new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://somenamespace"));
```

Using the predefined `XNameSpace.Xmlns` doesn't work for the default (no prefix) namespace, so just `"xmlns"` has to do.