# Multiple complex Xml Namespaces XDocument object

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xml-documentation

I am creating an xml document using c# XDocument object, however the namespaces in the document are really complex & cannot find a suitable solution for it. I have tried searching and implementing answers from other similiar threads but it seems to be failing for some reason or other.

Can someone please help me with this.

Following is the document namespace I am looking for:

```
   <abcd:orderinfo xmlns:abcd="http://example.com" OrderSchemaId="2017/abc-xyz/1234" 
    xmlns:ddex="http://example.com/1234"
    xmlns:abcd="http://example.com/20170718/xyz"
    xmlns:ms1234="http://example.com/20170718/ms1667"
    xmlns:ms1234x="http://example.com/20170718/ms1667x"
    xmlns:ms506b1="http://example.com/20170718/ms16672x1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/xml/2017/abc-comm/1234/abc.xsd">
  </abcd:orderinfo>
```

Comment: Can we see some c# code, please?

Comment: ... together with [How to set the default XML namespace for an XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082686/205233) where Michael has the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082686/205233)

Comment: Instead, show us what you have tried & what is the error you got..

Comment: @Filburt, thanks for the link, that solved the issue.