# Why xmlns appears at the parents' node in DGML file writing?

Tags: c#, dgml

When I save a `DGML` file, unnecessary `XNamespace` appears.

This is a code of saving `DGML` file.

```
public void saveDGMLFile()
{
    Debug.Log("Save DGML file!");

    XNamespace xNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml";
    xDoc = new XDocument();
    XElement root = new XElement(
        xNamespace + "DirectedGraph",
        new XAttribute("name", "root"));

    xDoc.Add(root);
    XElement parent = xDoc.Root;
    XElement nodes = new XElement("Nodes");

    foreach (var e in exploded_positions)
    {

        XElement item = new XElement("Node");
        item.SetAttributeValue("Id", e.Item1.name);
        item.SetAttributeValue("Category", 0);
        item.SetAttributeValue(XmlConvert.EncodeName("start_position"), (e.Item2.x + " " + e.Item2.y + " " + e.Item2.z));
        item.SetAttributeValue(XmlConvert.EncodeName("end_position"), (e.Item3.x + " " + e.Item3.y + " " + e.Item3.z));
        nodes.Add(item);
    }

    parent.Add(nodes);

    XElement links = new XElement("Links");
    XElement link = new XElement("Link");
    links.Add(link);
    parent.Add(links);

    XElement categories = new XElement("Categories");
    XElement category = new XElement("category");
    categories.Add(category);
    parent.Add(categories);

    xDoc.Save(outputFileName);
}
```

And this is an output `DGML` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DirectedGraph name="root" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
  <Nodes xmlns="">
    <Node Id="PTC_EXP_Blasensensor-Adapter-+-" Category="0" start_position="0 0 0" end_position="0 0 -0.7573751" />
    <Node Id="PTC_EXP_BML_Mutter_UNF-2B_1-14-" Category="0" start_position="0 0 0" end_position="0 0.7573751 0" />
    <Node Id="PTC_EXP_BUSAKSHAMBAN_OR1501300N" Category="0" start_position="0 0 0" end_position="0.7573751 0 0" />
  </Nodes>
  <Links xmlns="">
    <Link />
  </Links>
  <Categories xmlns="">
    <category />
  </Categories>
</DirectedGraph>
```

As you can see, `xmlns=""` of `XNameSpace` appears after the parents' node, `Nodes`, `Links`, and `Categories`.
How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you set the namespace on the root element to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml`, it's only affecting *that* element, it doesn't become the default for the whole document - child elements you add to it will still have a default/empty namespace.

That's why, when the XML is output those elements have the `xmlns` attribute to distinguish that they are not in the same namespace.

To change that, when creating the child elements you can add the namespace as you have done for the `DirectedGraph` root element - for example:

```
XElement nodes = new XElement(xNamespace + "Nodes");
```

Once they have the same element as the root node, they will no longer be output with an empty `xmlns` attribute.

Alternatively, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874422/how-to-set-the-default-xml-namespace-for-an-xdocument) for a method to do that for all child nodes in a document.